# Doing a global OR with the db abstraction layer

Tags: database

I have a function that makes a db query using `db_select`. The problem I'm having is that in a function elsewhere, the query object is applied a couple of conditions, and I want to add an OR clause but the final query ends with an `AND` instead of an `OR`.

Simplified example:

```
function a() {
    $q = db_select('table', 't');
    $q->addField('t', 'field1');
    b($q);
    // Here I want to add an OR so that the query
    // Selects the conditions applied in b()
    // or something else
    $q->execute();
}

function b($q) {
    $q->condition('t.field1', 'some val', '=');
    $q->condition('t.field2', 'some val', '=');
}
```

The way this example is, it would compile to something like

```
SELECT field1 FROM table AS t WHERE t.field1 = 'some val' AND t.field2 = 'some val'
```

I want to make it so that it compiles to

```
SELECT field1 FROM table AS t WHERE t.field1 = 'some val' AND t.field2 = 'some val' OR t.field3 = 'some val';
```

And the OR should be added in place of my comment in `a()`. How would I go about that in a proper way?

Right now I'm solving it with

```
$q->where(' 1 = 1) OR (t.field3 = :v', array(':v' => 'some val'));
```

which compiles to:

```
SELECT field1 FROM table AS t WHERE t.field1 = 'some val' AND t.field2 = 'some val' AND (1 = 1) OR t.field3 = 'some val';
```

but I feel that is just ugly, not to mention potentially buggy.

Using db_or instead of the line above results in this:

```
SELECT field1 FROM table AS t WHERE t.field1 = 'some val' AND t.field2 = 'some val' AND (field1 = 'some val');
```

That because the db_or crease some sort of combo, and you have to add more than one condition:

```
$or = db_or()->condition(...);
$or->condition(...);
```

Finally, it would be great to go a step further and create a query like

```
SELECT field1 FROM table AS t WHERE (... AND ...) OR ...
```

**Edit**: The example here is very simple, compared to the actual code, and I can't really modify the `b` function. I need to do the `OR` right where the comment is in `a()`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to nest `db_and()` and `db_or()` calls, and pass the result into a `condition()` call. See [Conditional Clauses](https://www.drupal.org/node/310086) documentation page for more information.

> The first parameter of condition() can also accept another conditional
>   object. That inner conditional object will be incorporated into the
>   outer conditional, surrounded by parentheses. The inner object may
>   also use a different conjunction than the outer object. That way, one
>   can build complex nested conditional structures by creating and
>   building up conditional objects "bottom up".
>
> The db_condition() helper function will return a new conditional
>   object. It takes a single parameter that is the conjunction that
>   object will use. In general, the helper methods db_and(), db_or(), and
>   db_xor() will cover almost any expected case. That allows conditionals
>   to be inserted inline in a query for a very compact syntax.

```
function a() {
  $q = db_select('table', 't');
  $q->addField('t', 'field1');
  $q->condition(db_or()->condition(b($q))->condition('t.field3', 'some val', '=');
  $q->execute();
}

function b($q) {
  return db_and()
    ->condition('t.field1', 'some val', '=');
    ->condition('t.field2', 'some val', '=');
}
```

This should produce the query `SELECT field1 FROM table t WHERE ((t.field1 = 'some val' AND t.field2 = 'some val') OR (t.field3 = 'some val'))`.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know, but not applicable in my case. The example I showed is a very simplified one. The actual code does more than that. The guy who did the initial implementation made a function that can be called to apply different changes to the query depending on a few parameters passed to the function. So, I can't really modify b(). I should have noted that in my question.